# extract_first only resulting in first item only .extract() does not work

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I hope that you're all well. I am trying to learn Python through web-scraping. My project at the moment is to scrape data from a games store. I am initially wanting to follow a product link and print the response from each link. There are 60 game links on the page that I wish for Scrapy to follow. Below is the code.

```
import scrapy


class GameSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['365games.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.365games.co.uk/3ds-games/']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_games = response.xpath('//*[@id="product_grid"]')

        for game in all_games:
            game_url = game.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').extract_first()

            yield scrapy.Request(game_url, callback=self.parse_game)

    def parse_game(self, response):
        print(response.status)
```

When I run this code scrapy runs and goes through the first link and prints the response, but stops. When I change the code to .extract() I get the following,

TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list

The same applies with .get()/.getall() being that .get() only returns the first and .getall() displays the above error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, but please be gentle I am trying to learn.

Thanks in advance and best regards,

Gav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that you are passing a list instead of a string to `scrapy.Request`. This tells us that `game_url` is actually a list, when you want a string. You are very close to the right thing here, but I believe your problem is that you are looping in the wrong place. You first XPath returns just a single item, rather than a list of items. It is within this that you want to find your `game_url`s leading to

```py
def parse(self, response):
    product_grid = response.xpath('//*[@id="product_grid"]')
    for game_url in product_grid.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').getall():
        yield scrapy.Request(game_url, callback=self.parse_game)
```

You could also combine your xpath queries to directly to

```py
def parse(self, response):
    all_games = response.xpath('//*[@id="product_grid"]//h3/a/@href')
    for game_url in all_games.getall():
        yield scrapy.Request(game_url, callback=self.parse_game)
```

In this case you could also use [`follow` instead of creating a new `Request` directly.](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests) You can even directly pass a selector rather than a string to `follow` so you don't need to `getall()`, and it knows how to deal with `<a>` elements so you don't need the `@href` either!

```py
def parse(self, response):
    for game_url in response.xpath('//*[@id="product_grid"]//h3/a'):
        yield response.follow(game_url, callback=self.parse_game)
```